# what happens to a question that is voted to be closed

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions

I was in the health S.E. There was a question the title was breathing vs energy. I think that it was closed. Now I don't even see it do they erease the question or put somewhere else? I personally may have a use of this question. At the end of my question I added that I need  this question this isn't the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a "closed" or “on hold” question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions are [automatically deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/215468) when they meet certain criteria. Either the question was deleted by moderators or automatically deleted by the system as detailed in the link above.

It sounds likely that the question was deleted due to this rule:

> If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past 9 days
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.

But we'll need a link or more details about the question to know for certain.

---

Deleted questions aren't accessible to people the don't have the [access to moderator tools privilege](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), set to 2,000 reputation points on beta sites like Health. The linked privilege page has more information on deleted questions.

Comment: I don't remember when it was closed. It reminded me what a therapist told me and I didn't think it could possibly be it was so off , I didn't except it. Until I saw this question.

Comment: @Nachmen if it was negative score without answers, it could have been deleted by [30-days roomba script](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/165773) which doesn't care if question is closed or not